# Subsetting duplicate rows in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
Name    State    Gender    OtherVariables
Sam     CO       M
Sam     CO       F
Sam     CO       M
Jim     CO       M
Jim     WY       M
```

The following code gives me all of the duplicate names: (Sam and Jim):

```
def list_duplicates(seq):
  seen = set()
  seen_add = seen.add
  seen_twice = set(x for x in seq if x in seen or seen_add(x))
  return list(seen_twice)

dups = list_duplicates(df.name)
```

But what I want is:

```
Name    State    Gender
Sam     CO       M
```

I only want those rows with the same Name, State and Gender. So Jim shouldn't be there. The "OtherVariables" are different for each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['Name','State','Gender'])]
print (df)

  Name State Gender
2  Sam    CO      M
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated` with the `subset` argument.

Example:

```
duplicates = df.duplicated(subset=['Name', 'State', 'Gender'])
df[duplicates]
```

[See the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help.